# how can I Delay and redirect

Tags: javascript

I have forum v bulletin
I need to redirect a visitor to redirect.php page automatically after a short delay,countdown redirect , 
when he clicks download attachment or external link.
Is there any possible way to do that in a .htaccess  (JavaScript)  code or any thing ..

Comment: I have forum v bulletin I need to redirect a visitor to example.php page .. automatically after a short delay,countdown when he clicks the download attachment already upload at my server or external link posted in my forum . Is there any possible way to do that in a .htaccess (JavaScript) code or any thing ..
    my site : [link](shneler.com/vb)
    example attachment URL : [link](http://shneler.com/vb/attachment.php?attachmentid=2063&d=1380201538)
    Thank you

Answer (score 2):

it is simple but you should Google for it

```
var delay = 100;
var button = document.getElementById("id o button");

button.onClick = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
    },delay)
};
```

Comment: Hello:1: what you mean Google for it ? 2: more  more clarification i m not  Professional   i need like this included any external links or any attachment   my site  shneler.com/vb  the attachment like this  URL  shneler.com/vb/attachment.php?attachmentid=2141&d=1380465993

Comment: i mean search Google or answer because it is very simple and there are lots of  topic about 

please vote and verify my answer

Comment: Hello:1: what you mean Google for it ? 2: more  more clarification i m not  Professional   i need like this                      <script src="js/anon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
protected_links = "javascript://,yoursite.com";

auto_anonymize();
//--></script>                    included any external links or any attachment   my site  shneler.com/vb  the attachment like this  URL  shneler.com/vb/attachment.php?attachmentid=2141&d=1380465993              please send me y email I m mohammad from Jordan